# How to make two elements both fill parent element (height)?

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems making two elements align perfectly. They're in the same line, the one to the left is an input element and the one to the right is a div, in a "bar" (also a div). Please see the picture.

[How it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olyHm.png)

What I want it to look like is for the two elements to have the exact same height, filling from top to bottom of the grey div with classname "wrapper".

I have simplified the code, and the button clearly doesn't work. What you can see in the code here is a  small part of a react app, but that's irrelevant because the problem is in the CSS. The button needs to be a div.

**The CSS code:**

```
body{background-color: black}

.wrapper
{
    background-color: grey;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

input
{
    font-size: 30px;
}

.button
{
  background-color: green;

  padding-left: 10px; 

  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
}
```

**and the HTML code:**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <input type="text" size="5"/>

        <div class="button">
            <p>
                Button
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I've tried setting the "display" of the elements to "inline" and "inline-block" back and forth, and tried to set the height to 100% for these elements which doesn't seem to work.

Thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use flexbox

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

    <input type="text" size="5" />

    <div class="button">
      <p>
        Button
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Everything seems like could be fixed with a Flexbox. It's amazing lol.

Answer (score 0):

On the wrapper class add `display: flex;` and on the input tag add `flex: stretch;`

Comment: display: flex; seems to be enough in my case. Thank you!